# WARNING: Failed to add policy job since the add condition is not satisfied

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-alloydb

I'm trying to schedule automatic recommendation and population by following this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/alloydb/docs/columnar-engine/manage-content-recommendations#auto-auto).

I'm trying to run this query

`SELECT google_columnar_engine_add_policy( 'RECOMMEND_AND_POPULATE_COLUMNS', 'EVERY', 10, 'HOURS');`

But this query fails. I've tried many other combinations of `policy_interval`, `duration`, `time_unit`, and it fails with the same error every time.

Only one case works, that is when `policy_interval` is "IMMEDIATE" but this is not what I'm after.

Comment: What is the error you get when you run the query.Also share the query for other combination.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added the error message. But I don't have access to those environments now.

Comment: Let me knowif  my recommendations helped or you are looking for some information.

Comment: Maybe wait for the duration of 10 hrs before checking the results?

Answer (score 1):

The basic steps to follow for the configuation  and usage are as below:

- Enable the columnar engine.
- Let the engine's recommendation feature observe your workload and
  gather query statistics
- Size the engine's column store based on the recommendation feature's
  analysis.
- Enable automatic population of the    column store by the
  recommendation feature.
- Let the recommendation    feature observe    your workload and
  automatically add columns to the    column store.

The query that you are trying to run is for Schedule automatic recommendation and population

```
(
  'RECOMMEND_AND_POPULATE_COLUMNS',
  policy_interval, duration, time_unit
);
```

`policy_interval`: The time interval determining when the policy runs. You can specify these values:

`'IMMEDIATE'`: The RECOMMEND_AND_POPULATE_COLUMNS operation runs immediately one time. When you use this value, specify `0` and `'HOURS'` for the duration and time_unit parameters.

`'AFTER'`: The RECOMMEND_AND_POPULATE_COLUMNS operation runs once when the duration time_unit amount of time passes.
`'EVERY'`: The RECOMMEND_AND_POPULATE_COLUMNS operation runs repeatedly every duration time_unit amount of time.

`duration`: The number of time_units. For example, `24`.

`time_unit`: The unit of time for duration. You can specify `'DAYS'`or `'HOURS'`.

Please check if this was followed from setup to configuration and try again.Also as you mentioned, the specific errors are not available with you for clearly understanding the breakpoint here.I would recommend you to check the below link for reference.

https://cloud.google.com/alloydb/docs

https://cloud.google.com/alloydb/docs/faq

Hope that helps.